emmeans working outside function but not inside (scoping issue?)
Here is a toy example. Why does emmeans() work outside my function, but inside it throws the error "Error in eval(cl) : object 'datin' not found"?
testdat = data.frame(y=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                     x=c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
                     id=c("X","X","Y","X","X","Y"))

test = function(datin){
  model=aov(y~x+Error(id), data = datin)
  print(summary(model))
  # The function works fine up until here (it prints the summary)
  # After this, at the emm step, it returns the error "Error in eval(cl) : object 'datin' not found"
  emm=emmeans::emmeans(model,~x)
  return(emm)
}

test(testdat)

# Here, there is no error
model=aov(y~x+Error(id), data = testdat)
summary(model)
emm=emmeans::emmeans(model,~x)
emm


Yes, looks like a scoping error -- you should report it to the package maintainer at https://github.com/rvlenth/emmeans/issues .

Running traceback(), way down the stack I see some oddities - eval(cl) twice in a row?   datin turns into data ?    :::   10: terms(formula, "Error", data = data)
9: aov(formula = y ~ x + Error(id), data = datin, contrasts = list(
x = "contr.sum"))
8: eval(cl)
7: eval(cl)

What looks to be the same scoping errror shows up here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71515367/   with respect to a different library.

For some reason, it works when I use model=do.call(aov,list(function=y~x+Error(id),data=datin))! Any idea why this would fix the scoping error?
